# Copying a specific cell on Workbook1 and pasting it next to a date on Workbook2

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

i have been digging around for many hours and cant find a code to suit my need.  I have seen similar but havent been able to adapt to this one.  I have data on workbook 1 that looks like the following

```
5/11/2020 XXXX
5/11/2020 YYYY
```

This workbook gets updated and the date and data next to it get modified each day (always in the same cells). i would like the data to get pasted next to the dates in workbook2 that also are presented as

```
5/09/2020 XXXX
5/09/2020 YYYY
5/10/2020 XXXX
5/10/2020 YYYY
5/11/2020 [blank]
5/11/2020 [blank]
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: The dates were supposed to go one below the other, not next to each other, sorry.

Comment: Unclear what you need - try to explain the ask here a little more (photos of starting/end points tend to help). Also, what have you tried? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Basically Workbook 1 gets renewed every day and has A1 and A2 with the same date (usually today) and numbers next to them.
Workbook 2 has column A with all the dates of the month duplicated (as shown above, because Workbook1 brings two data per date). I would like to copy the data from Workbook 1 and paste them on Workbook 2 next to the dates that are in A1 and A2 on Workbook 1.